# Make Apache write log entry also at start of download

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, logging

Apache writes log entries *after* it has finished serving a request.

Is there a way to make it log the *start* of a request, possibly to a fifo, and preferably only according to some criteria (file size, or else file type or something).

We sometimes have very big downloads running over HTTP, and it would be useful to be able to see that they have started.

Answer (score 1):

The module mod_log_forensic provides exactly this functionality:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_forensic.html

It is available for both apache httpd v2.2 and v2.4